# Showing that two quadratic surface are normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book "Algebraic Geometry" by Robin Hartshone, or GTM 52 for short, there is a problem of showing that two quadratic surface $Q_1: xy=zw$ and $Q_2: xy=z^2$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are normal.

I have got no idea to solve it except basing on the condition of smoothness. However, that problem is only in section 3, but smooth condition appears only in section 5.

Is there other way to solve this problem with the knowledge in section 3? Please give me some hints.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

For $Q2$, look forward to exercise II, 6.4,  just as Hartshorne himself suggests.
Or use Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*, Example 4 ( page 65) where he shows why the relevant ring $k[x,y][\sqrt {xy}]$ is normal because $k[x,y]$ is factorial  and $xy$ square-free.

For $Q1$, change variables so as to obtain the equation $s^2-t^2+u^2-v^2=0$ and proceed as in $Q1$ to show that the relevant  ring $k[s,t,u][\sqrt {s^2-t^2+u^2}]$ is normal.

Comment: Elencwajg: Can you give a hint for changing the variable for Q1 to get $s^2-t^2+u^2-v^2=0$ ?